# Why is this matrix function smooth?

Tags: derivatives, smooth-manifolds

Let $A$ be a real, invertible, $k \times k$ matrix, let $B$ be a real $k \times (n - k)$ matrix, and let $C$ be a real $(m-k) \times k$ matrix.

How is the function
$$ F:(A,B,C) \mapsto CA^{-1}B $$
smooth (i.e. $C^\infty$)? What is the derivative of $F$?

I saw this function in a proof that the set of $m \times n$ matrices with rank $k$ form a submanifold of the set of all $m \times n $ matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is obviously smooth, since entries of the product are quadratic polynomials in the entries of the two matrices.

The entries of $A^{-1}$ are rational polynomials of the entries of $A$, which may not be obvious at first but is a consequence of Cramer's rule. Therefore matrix inversion is smooth away from $\det A =0$.

Finally since matrix multiplication is linear, the differential satisfies the product rule:
$$dF = dCA^{-1}B - CA^{-1}dAA^{-1}B + CA^{-1}dB$$
where the formula for the differential of $A^{-1}$ can be derived from differentiating both sides of
$$A^{-1}A = I.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is invertible, and $\|H\| < {1 \over \|A^{-1}\|}$, then we have
$(A+H)^{-1} = ((I+HA^{-1})A)^{-1} = A^{-1} (I+HA^{-1})^{-1}$.
Since $\|HA^{-1}\| \le \|H\| \|A^{-1}\| < 1$, the series
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k(HA^{-1})^k$ is absolutely convergent, and it is straightforward to verify that $(I+HA^{-1})^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k(HA^{-1})^k$, and so
$(A+H)^{-1} = A^{-1}-A^{-1} HA^{-1} + A^{-1} \sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k(HA^{-1})^k$.

For sufficiently small $H$, the latter term is bounded by $K\|H\|^2$ for some
$K$, hence we see that the map $\operatorname{inv}(A) =A^{-1}$ is differentiable, and 
$D\operatorname{inv}(A)(H) = -A^{-1} HA^{-1}$.

It follows by induction and the product rule that $\operatorname{inv}$ is smooth.

The map $L(X) = CAB$ is linear, hence differentiable, and we have
$DL(X)(H) = CHB$.

Since $F = L \circ \operatorname{inv}$, we see that
$DF(A)(H) = DL(\operatorname{inv}(A) )(D\operatorname{inv}(A)(H)) $, and so
$DF(A)(H) = -C A^{-1} HA^{-1}B $.